# Get JSON objects out of HTML string

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

```
htmlStr = "<option value='1'>Hello</option><option value='2'>Goodbye</option>
```

How to turn the above html string into:

```
list_Array = [{value: "1", text: "Hello"},{value: "2", text: "Goodbye"}]
```

Comment: Do you know it is always options?

Comment: Also, is this a string, or is it in the DOM. It would change the approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `<select>` element to insert the html into then iterate that element's `options` collection and map to new array

```js
const htmlStr = "<option value='1'>Hello</option><option value='2'>Goodbye</option>";

const sel = document.createElement('select');
sel.innerHTML = htmlStr;

const list_Array = Array.from(sel.options).map(function(opt){
  return {value: opt.value, text: opt.text};
})

console.log(list_Array)
```